# Sequelize defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4 return null

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I upgrade version of Sequelize to 6.21.4 (from 6.5.0)
my code have id determine with migration file:

```
id: { type: DataTypes.UUID, primaryKey: true, defaultValue: fn("uuid_generate_v4") },
```

failed to work with error  message: Invalid value Fn { fn: 'uuid_generate_v4', args: [] }
I try to update to:

```
id: { type: DataTypes.UUID, primaryKey: true, defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4 },
```

it seems return null and not creating uuid as expected when no sending id.
I don't want to demine it manually.

Comment: Your last line seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: which Sequelize version? do you succeed to create a row without id and get it automatically create this row with uuid?

Comment: Tested with 6.21.4: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/bfe21c8a83781bac3e1f39d37b00d492

Answer (score 0):

I always use this successfully:

```js
defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()')
```

which I suppose is an equivalent of

```js
defaultValue: Sequelize.fn("uuid_generate_v4") }
```

Comment: I have already try this and the same issue not working on the new 6.21.4 sequelize version

Comment: Are you sure that Sequelize upgrade was the only thing? Do you have the `uuid-ossp` extension installed?